# Options for embedded video on website other than YouTube?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, youtube, html5-video

Been having trouble with YouTube lately with regards to autoplay, looping and playlists. Currently using the AS3 embedded player and it was working fine until recently when autoplay and playlist options became mutually exclusive. I am also finding the loop option doesn't work with autoplay.

So, looking at options other than YouTube as we will have access to the video anyway and can either upload or stream using whatever technology is appropriate. My application is for touchscreen interactive kiosks which will be largely unattended and I want to be able to run embedded video with all controls turned off to prevent anyone from jumping off to some other website at any point. This is crucial! I don't mind if a touch can pause the video like it does with YouTube but links must not be available to jump out.

My web app is written in Rails 3 with HTML, CSS3 and JQuery where required. It runs on IE8/9 on the kiosks and Safari mainly during development. I'm using Heroku.com for hosting.

Hopefully I've given enough background here to attract some good answers but please let me know if I've missed anything important.

Thanks for your time,
Craig.

Comment: Feedback on either of the 2 answers?

Answer (score 0):

This service is awesome in quality and price.

http://sublimevideo.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using heroku for your hosting, you should take advantage of their add-on. The interface is super clean and you have full flexibility to mold playlists or behavior.

Panda Stream
http://addons.heroku.com/pandastream